# how to create iphone style slider buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, uibutton, uislider

I am trying to design iphone style slider buttons.I have used Jquery iButton plugin.It worked fine when I used this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
```

But I changed this code into

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js">
```

It still did not work.I am trying to develop offline application. How do I make it work locally.

Comment: try renaming `jquery.min.js` file to `jquery.js`